# Configuration Error right after creating new MVC 4 project in VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm creating a new MVC 4 Web Application in Visual Studio 2012. The new project comes with a default template so I wanted to try running it, but I got the following error message:

```
Line 247:      <providers>
Line 248:        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
Line 249:        <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
Line 250:      </providers>
Line 251:    </membership>

Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config    Line: 249
```

I tried to search for the keywords `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider` and `MySQLMembershipProvider` using CTRL+F in the entire solution but it says "text was not found".

Note that I have not made any changed to the project, it's a brand new project that I've just created.

What exactly is the issue?

Additional information: This error occurred during the run-time and the error message is displayed in the browser. (No compile-error)

Comment: What's the actual error message you are receiving? The lines you quoted are typically located within the `web.config` file in the root of your project.

Comment: The reason might be that your project has reference to MySql Membership provider, but the project itself doesn't have reference to MySql connector assemblies

Comment: @Aschratt That is the error message. I copy and paste the entire error message here.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov I'm not sure what you're referring to, but I have not made any changes to the application itself. Like I said, it's a brand new project so I'm assuming it should run properly.

Comment: You have to add the reference to the MySql assemblies (Your Project > References > Right Click > Add Reference...; or simply Google) or install them using NuGet (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Web/6.8.3)

Comment: @Aschratt It works - Please write this in the answer section so that I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MySQLMembershipProvider` is a part of the `MySql.Web.Security` assembly which is somehow missing from your references. In case you have the MySql SDK installed locally, you can simply search the assembly from the "Add References..." menu (from the context menu of your project). Alternatively you can install the respective [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Web/6.8.3).